# How to generate proper SQL request

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database where ID is int value 7 or 8 digits (2500859 or 15201234) long so i need to generate correct SQL request.
I tried to

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table WHERE FORMAT(Id, '0#######') LIKE '25'
```

but it doesn't works.
Could you please me generate correct request.

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table WHERE FORMAT(Id, '0#######') LIKE '25'
```

result is 0

Comment: could you please explain, what you want to select ?

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Iit is very likely that the condition should be WHERE FORMAT(Id, '0#######') LIKE '25%'

Comment: And maybe FORMAT(2500859)='2,500,859' - this is not LIKE '25%'. Please check format pattern. CAST(id as varchar)?

Comment: Tanks everyone. I've found SQL string I required. It is:

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(FORMAT(Id, '0#######'),5) as INT)) 
FROM Column 
WHERE CAST(LEFT(FORMAT(Id, '0#######'),3) AS INT) = Number"
```

This string returns the output which I asked for.

Comment: How does this work? There are no LEFT() and RIGHT() functions in SQLite.

Comment: May be. I using this request via SqlClient in visualstudio.

Answer (score -1):

Postgresql:

```
select max(id) from kkkk where length(id::varchar) =7;
select max(id) from kkkk where length(id::varchar) =8;

    ------------ method 1
select * from kkkk where length(id::varchar) =7;
select * from kkkk where length(id::varchar) =8;

---------------method 2
select 
case when length(id::varchar) =7 then id end as "ids with 7 caracters",
case when length(id::varchar) =8 then id end as "ids with 8 caracters"
from kkkk
```

Demo

[image]

Comment: These queries do not even run in SQLite.

Comment: That's postgresql and the same function exists in SQLite all what you need to do is to use cast function to cast IDs as text and to apply length function as in postgresql ie: select max(id) from table where length(cast (id as text))=7

Comment: (1) *That's postgresql...* Why? The question is tagged SQLite not Postgresql. (2) *what you need to do is to use cast function to cast IDs as text...* No, in SQLite there is no need for casting.